# How to create a new column that's name contains a variable name (in a loop)?

Tags: r, loops

I have a vector containing row index numbers and I'd like to create a new dummy variable based on those numbers, i.e. rows that are present in the vector would have a value of 1 in the new variable. I'm attempting this in a loop and I need the new variable name to contain the value of the loop variable. The problem seems to be that I'm unable to assign any values to that variable unless it exists, but I'm also unable to create it.

Below is an example with some pseudo data and commands.

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:20, 
                 year = sample(2011:2013, 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 dum = sample(0:1, 20, rep = TRUE), 
                 var = sample(10:99, 20))
for (x in 2011:2013) {
# Below I take a subset of data to test models for different years.
  assign(paste0("subset.", x), df[df$year == x, ])
  # Here I would test a model.
# Below I imitate matching of propensity scores and create an object that contains 
# row indexes of control group.
  set.seed(x)
  assign(paste0("matching.", x), list(data = df, index.control = sample(1:20, 4)))
# Below I attempt to take the row indexes ofcontrol goup from the created 'matching' object and create 
# a new dummy variable that determines the control group. None of the commands work.
  assign(get(paste0("subset.", x))[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control, paste0("control.", x)], 1)
  get(paste0("subset.", x))[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control, paste0("control.", x)] <- 1
  get(paste0("subset.", x))[[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control, paste0("control.", x)]] <- 1
}
```

Below are the errors that are displayed when runnig the three last commands.

```
> assign(get(paste0("subset.", x))[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control, paste0("control.", x)], 1)
Error in assign(get(paste0("subset.", x))[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control,  : 
  invalid first argument

> get(paste0("subset.", x))[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control, paste0("control.", x)] <- 1
Error in get(paste0("subset.", x))[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

> get(paste0("subset.", x))[[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control, paste0("control.", x)]] <- 1
Error in get(paste0("subset.", x))[[get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Thus, my goal here is to create a new "dummy" variable that contains the loop variable name and assign the value of `1` to it where the row numbers match the numbers in `get(paste0("matching.", x))$index.control`.

Comment: Using `get()` and `assign()` is usually a sign that you are doing things wrong (or in a very un-R-like way). You probably should be using named lists to store elements rather than creating a bunch of variables. It would be better to start with just a description of the problem and the desired output rather than focusing on how you've attempted to do it.

Comment: Please show an example of what you want; if you have to test per year, there is a split to be performed and I doubt (with your example) you would have index.control based on 20 possible values (but restrict per year. As MrFlick highlitgjt, assign  and get is in most cases not welcome. I would propose first have a look at `split(df,df$year)` that prepare a list with every yearly data.frame stored.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an apply solution where you store matching indices and subsetted dataframes using `lapply` and then run needed value operation on them using `mapply`. Once done, use `assign()` to output to multiple objects.

```
# LIST OF YEARLY DATAFRAMES
subsetdfs <- lapply(2011:2013, function(x) df[df$year == x,])

# LIST OF YEARLY RANDOM IDS
matchinglists <- lapply(2011:2013, function(x) {
                                     set.seed(x)
                                     sample(1:20, 4)
                                  }
                        )

# USER-DEFINED FUNCTION TO ASSIGN NAMED COLUMN AND VALUE
dfprocess <- function(x, y){
                x['control'] <- NA
                x[y,'control'] <- 1
                x <- x[!is.na(x$id),]
                return(x)
             }

# MAPPLY TO MAP ITERATIVELY EACH LIST FOR FCT
dflist <- mapply(dfprocess, x=subsetdfs, y=matchinglists)
dflist    
#         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
# id      Integer,6 Integer,9 Integer,5
# year    Integer,6 Integer,9 Integer,5
# dum     Integer,6 Integer,9 Integer,5
# var     Integer,6 Integer,9 Integer,5
# test    Numeric,6 Numeric,9 Numeric,5
# control Numeric,6 Numeric,9 Numeric,5

# CREATE MULTIPLE FINAL DFS
for (i in 2011:2013) {
      assign(paste0('subset', i), 
             data.frame(dflist[, i - 2010]),
             envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```